# Removing Border / Background using Custom CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a custom 404 page. Example of the same can be found @ http://www.techquark.com/123123

I need to make the box border go away and background as white.

For that I pasted the below CSS :

```
.status-msg-border {border: 0;}
.status-msg-body {background-color: #ffffff;}
.status-msg-wrap {width: 100%; margin: 0px auto;}
.status-msg-bg {background: transparent;}
```

But it's not working and the box still has border and color. Below is the 404 page code :

```
<div class='status-msg-wrap'>
<div class='status-msg-body'>
<div style="text-align: center;" trbidi="on">
<h2>
404 Page Not Found</h2>
Sorry but the page you are looking for cannot be found.
<br/><br/>
If you're in denial and think this is a conspiracy that cannot possibly be true, please try using the search box below or <a href="http://www.techquark.com/p/contact-us.html" target="_blank">contact me</a>.
<br/><br/>
<form action="/search" id="searchThis" method="get" style="display: inline; margin: 20px auto;">
<input id="searchBox" name="q" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" type="text" value="Search this blog" vinput="" /> <input id="searchButton" type="submit" value="Go" /></form>
<br/><br/>
You may also want to move to the <a href="http://www.techquark.com/" target="_blank">homepage</a> for a fresh start of our relationship.
<br/><br/>
<a href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wNOn6Ndu7ws/WPCqTnFAxGI/AAAAAAAAozQ/NlRrQ9so7awQJdAwXcL9ZAUR08EV2lutQCK4B/s1600/404.jpg" imageanchor="1"><img border="0" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-wNOn6Ndu7ws/WPCqTnFAxGI/AAAAAAAAozQ/NlRrQ9so7awQJdAwXcL9ZAUR08EV2lutQCK4B/s1600/404.jpg" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the output, I'm expecting :

[image]

Any help on the same would be appreciated!

Comment: Hi @Shubham Can you elaborate it a bit more. I mean which box are you mentioning.

Comment: Hi, @SreenathPG. I just added output screenshot I'm expecting to main question.

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, try adding border:1px solid transparent; and for the background try background-color:white;. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. I used the new code as : 

.status-msg-border {1px solid transparent;}
.status-msg-body {background-color:white;}
.status-msg-wrap {width: 100%; margin: 0px auto;}
.status-msg-bg {background: transparent;}

Answer (score 0):

You need to make overwrite as you are using custom css.

```
.status-msg-border {border: 0 !important;}
.status-msg-body {background-color: #ffffff !important;}
.status-msg-wrap {width: 100%; margin: 0px auto !important;}
.status-msg-bg {background: transparent !important;}
```

try the above code it should work definitely.

Answer (score 0):

When I checked your site I found the following in the console:

```
.status-msg-border {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
    -moz-opacity: .4;
    opacity: .4;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

remove the line `border: 1px solid #000;` and it should be fine

Or try `.status-msg-border { border-width: 0px; }`

hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't work as well. Looks like it is not taking any CSS into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Try `.status-msg-bg {display:none}`

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the site load was causing CSS overriding. I pasted the CSS at end of the site.

Even now the border and background gets loaded but it gets overrided again when site load completes. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score -1):

`<div class="status-msg-border" style="border: none; opacity: 0;">`

Just add these inline styles to your div